# Find a function continuous on $[0,2]$ differentiable on $(0,1) ,(1,2)$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, continuity

I need to find a function $\Psi:[0,2] \to \mathbb{R}$ which is

1. Continuous on $[0,2]$.
2. Differentiable on $(0,1),(1,2)$.
3. Satisfies initial condition $\Psi (t=0)=1$.
4. Satsifies the ODE $ d_t \Psi= -\Psi + F$ on $(0,1)$ and $(1,2)$, where $F$ is the function $F=0$ if $t\leq 1$, $F=1$ otherwise.

I can find a function that satisfies three of the four requirements but am struggling to find one that satisfies all four. For example $\Psi (t) =e^{-t} +F(t)$ satisfies all conditions except continuity. Any advice would be much appreciated.

Comment: The general solution of $d_t\Psi=-\Psi$ is $Ce^{-t}$. Do variation of parameter. This is, search for your solution in the form $C(t)e^{-t}$. You get that $C(t)$ satisfies $C'(t)=e^tF$. Integrating you get $C(t)$, which will be continuous, and differentiable where $F$ is continuous: $\Psi(t)=e^{-t}\int_{0}^{t}e^tF(t)dt$.

Comment: Thank you this helps a lot, However does this satisfy the initial condition? isnt the integral from zero to zero equal to zero? Which would mean $\Psi (t=0)=0$ not 1?

Comment: I thought it was zero. Yes, when you solve $C'=e^tF$ you get a constant $C(t)=\int_{0}^{t}e^tF(t)dt+D$. Adjust the $D$ to get the initial condition. Since it should be one we get that $D=1$. Then $\Psi(t)=e^{-t}\left(\int_{0}^{t}e^sF(s)ds+1\right)$

Comment: That makes sense. thank you